# Django/Python unable to find GDAL Library

Tags: python, django, macos, gdal, macos-catalina

I have installed GDAL in a virtual environement with the following commands:

```
$ brew install gdal
$ pip3 install gdal
```

When trying a python manage.py makemigrations or python manage.py runserver (or whatever) on the website code for which I installed it, I'm running into the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal2.4.0", "gdal2.3.0", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

I'm struggling to find good information on how to set this variable correctly, or general informations on how to solve the problem. I'm using MacOS Catalina. I have no experiences with GDAL, at this stage I just need to install it properly to make the website run on my machine and start contributing to the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv or anything of the sort? I'm guessing GDAL is not installed on the same environment as your Django installation.

Comment: @RedgrenGrumbholdt Yes I do. But I did my brew install an pip install while in this environement

Comment: Hmm...my gues is it's being installed on the system's env not your intented environment. If you do `pip freeze` in your environment does GDAL appear on the list?

Comment: Yes it does. I think I solved the problem by editing the libgdal.py file and adding the current version to the file_path array